# list.files() all files in directory and subdirectories

Tags: r

I'm trying to list all the files in a directories including subdirectories that end with `_input.txt`.

```
- folder 1
  - a_input.txt
  - folder 2
    - b_input.txt
```

If folder 1 were my working directory, I would like `list.files(pattern = "\\_input.txt$")` to be able to detect both `a_input.txt` and `b_input.txt`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

To list the matching files in all subdirectories, you can use `recursive = TRUE` in `list.files()`

```
list.files(pattern = "_input.txt$", recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: Any idea how to get the results without the sub directories prepended?  using "include.dirs = F" has no effect.

Comment: @86smopuiM Wrap in  `basename`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that has to do with the include.dirs = F not working?

Comment: @86smopuiM - I don't know what you are asking.  `basename(list.files(...))` will give *only* the file name, with no sub directory prepended.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, sorry I just didn't understand the way you phrased it!  Thank you.

Comment: Note the _ is part of the OP's question, not a special character. e.g. `list.files(pattern = ".txt$")` would find all txt files just fine!

Comment: How to extract the files' names  only, without the path?